# Python returning object "placement" instead of float

Tags: python, web-scraping, stock

I'm creating a web scraper that will be used to value stocks. The problem I got is that my code returns a object "placement" (Not sure what it should be called) instead of the value.

```
import requests

class Guru():

    MedianPE = 0.0

    def __init__(self, ticket):


        self.ticket = ticket

        try:

            url = ("https://www.gurufocus.com/term/pettm/"+ticket+"/PE-Ratio-TTM/")

            response = requests.get(url)
            htmlText = response.text
            firstSplit = htmlText
            secondSplit = firstSplit.split("And the <strong>median</strong> was <strong>")[1]
            thirdSplit = secondSplit.split("</strong>")[0]

            lastSplit = float(thirdSplit)

            try:
                Guru.MedianPE = lastSplit
            except:
                print(ticket + ": Median PE N/A")
        except:
            print(ticket + ": Median PE N/A")


    def getMedianPE(self):
        return float(Guru.getMedianPE)





g1 = Guru("AAPL")
g1.getMedianPE
print("Median + " + str(g1))
```

If I print the `lastSplit` inside the `__init__` it returns the value I want `15.53` but  when I try to get it by  the function `getMedianPE` I just get `Median + <__main__.Guru object at 0x0000016B0760D288>`

Thanks a lot for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are trying to cast a function object to a float.  Simply change `return float(Guru.getMedianPE)` to `return float(Guru.MedianPE)`

Comment: Sadly, it is not working still return the same `Median + <__main__.Guru object at 0x0000016B086368C8>` :/

Comment: when you call `g1.getMedianPe` add parentheses to the end, `g1.getMedianPE()`

Comment: Thank you. No idea how I missed that but it still returns `Median + <__main__.Guru object at 0x0000016B086368C8>`

Comment: Hmm, change return to `return float(self.MedianPE)` and store MedianPE in self, so `self.MedianPE = something` in constructor.  But it looks like you got an answer

Comment: I kind of did... Not sure if I can use it as I first intended. Thanks for the help hopefully I can solve it!

Comment: Think I see whats going on, everything in __init__ only exists while the constructor is in scope.  If you want to save an variable you must put self infront of it, `self.lastsplit = `  then in getMedian just `return float(self.lastsplit)` that should work.

Answer (score 0):

`getMedianPE` is a function (also called object method when part of a class), so you need to call it with parentheses. If you call it without parentheses, you get the method/function itself rather than the result of calling the method/function.

The other problem is that `getMedianPE` returns the function `Guru.getMedianPE` rather than the value `Guru.MedianPE`. I don't think you want MedianPE to be a class variable - you probably just want to set it as a default of 0 in **init** so that each object has its own median_PE value.

Also, it is not a good idea to include all of the scraping code in your **init** method. That should be moved to a scrape() method (or some other name) that you call after instantiating the object.

Finally, if you are going to print an object, it is useful to have a **str** method, so I added a basic one here.

So putting all of those comments together, here is a recommended refactor of your code.

```
import requests

class Guru():
    def __init__(self, ticket, median_PE=0):
        self.ticket = ticket
        self.median_PE = median_PE

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.ticket} {self.median_PE}'

    def scrape(self):
        try:
            url = f"https://www.gurufocus.com/term/pettm/{self.ticket}/PE-Ratio-TTM/"
            response = requests.get(url)
            htmlText = response.text
            firstSplit = htmlText
            secondSplit = firstSplit.split("And the <strong>median</strong> was <strong>")[1]
            thirdSplit = secondSplit.split("</strong>")[0]
            lastSplit = float(thirdSplit)
            self.median_PE = lastSplit
        except ValueError:
            print(f"{self.ticket}: Median PE N/A")
```

Then you run the code

```
>>>g1 = Guru("AAPL")
...g1.scrape()
...print(g1)
AAPL 15.53
```

Comment: Thank you! That works. But what if I want to return different values. For example if I scrape 4 different kinds of values but want to return them one by one. Also what if I want to return it as a float? I tried this `def __float__(self):
        return f'{self.median_PE}'`  Thanks again for the help

Comment: If you have other values that you want to capture, then declare them in __init__ and then you can set them in the scrape method just like median_PE.

Comment: The ```f''``` construct is for converting variables to strings, so you wouldn't use it to return a float. You are already casting median_PE to a float in the scrape method. You can ensure the default value is a float by making it 0.0 instead of 0.

Comment: Thank you but I can't get it to work the way I want. The only way can't be to get the value by using constructors I need a separate function for it.